# DynamoDB Query - GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Say if I had a DynamoDB table:

```
UserId: S
BookName: S
BorrowedTimestamp: S
HasReturned: B
```

UserId (partition) and BookName (range) would be keys on the base table.

However I want to query using the other non-key fields e.g. BorrowedTimestamp > 3days and HasReturned is false.

I think I'd need to setup a GSI for this query to work, but it doesn't sound right having a binary field, HasReturned, as the partition key (with BorrowedTimestamp as range key). Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a GSI, but it might be more efficient depending on your circumstances.

Lets take your example of BorrowedTimestamp > 3days. Im going to assume this is for a particular user, so you have a userid to query.

You could do a [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) with a `KeyConditionExpression` of `userid`, then a `FilterExpression` of `BorrowedTimestamp > 3days`. Lets say the user has 10 books and 2 of them have a `BorrowedTimestamp > 3days`. This query will cost you 10 RCU (Read Capacity Units). That's because a `FilterExpression` just filters out items in your result set - DynamoDB actually found all 10 items in the query.

Now lets say you have a GSI where the partition key was `userid` and the range key was `BorrowedTimestamp`. Your `KeyConditionExpression` could specify both the parition key of the `userid` and the range key of `BorrowedTimestamp > 3days`. The result would be exactly the same. However this time it would only cost you 2 RCUs, and those RCUs would come from the index capacity not the table capacity.

Less RCUs sounds good, but remember you have to purchase throughput capacity for your primary index and GSI separately. This can be less efficient because you can't share purchased throughput between queries that use your primary key and GSI.

Finally if you didn't want to specify a userid at all you would use a [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html). Scans sometimes don't scale well because they always evaluate every item in the table, but whether it works for you really depends on a lot of things (like how often you will use the scan, how many items you will have in the table etc).

Comment: The OP didn't make it clear if they want to specify the `userid` or not with every query, but if they do then a LSI would work instead of a GSI